# Merge Rows in Oracle with nulls in different columns

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, rows

My query is pulling a base population from two different customer tables based on demographics. Both tables share numerous columns, such as name, ID, city, state, and zip code. Table A contains 2 columns that are not in Table B (state2 and state3). Table B contains 1 column that is not in Table B (country).

I use a union to combine both base populations. Some names are duplicated from each base population, but not all of them. Some are unique to each base population, as they exist in one table but not the other. The union does not remove the duplicates that exist in both tables because they have info in Table A unique columns, but nulls in Table B unique column, and visa versa. I need to figure out how to combine them into one row, with all 3 of the columns showing applicable data. Please see example output:

```
ID   Name   City     State   State2   State3   Zip   Country   Phone   Order Year   Order Status
111  Bob    Anytown  MP                       55555    US     555-5555  2020         Valid
111  Bob    Anytown  MP       MP       MP     55555           555-5555  2020         Valid
```

I would like to return the following:

```
ID   Name   City     State   State2   State3   Zip   Country   Phone   Order Year   Order Status
111  Bob    Anytown  MP       MP        MP    55555    US     555-5555  2020         Valid
```

I tried to use not exists logic and also tried to join the unioned base onto itself with not null conditions but have not been able to get the results I am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Please add your best try to your question (via [Edit]).

Answer (score 0):

You need to coalesce the individual columns then grab the distinct combinations, as in:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d1.ID,
                COALESCE(d1.NAME, d2.NAME) AS NAME,
                COALESCE(d1.City, d2.City) AS City,
                COALESCE(d1.State, d2.State) AS State,
                COALESCE(d1.State2, d2.State2) AS State2,
                COALESCE(d1.State3, d2.State3) AS State3,
                COALESCE(d1.Zip, d2.Zip) AS Zip,
                COALESCE(d1.Country, d2.Country) AS Country,
                COALESCE(d1.Phone, d2.Phone) AS Phone,
                COALESCE(d1.Order_Year, d2.Order_Year) AS Order_Year,
                COALESCE(d1.Order_Status, d2.Order_Status) AS Order_Status
  FROM CUST_DATA d1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CUST_DATA d2
    ON d2.ID = d1.ID AND
       d2.ROWID <> d1.ROWID
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=43369b467626094f49ca3d0b1d8a70a6)

Answer (score 0):

If you have only issue with 3 `columns` then you can use `group by` and `max/min` to create one record with **non-null** data as following:

```
Select id, name, city, state,
       Max(state2) as state2,
       Max(state3) as state3,
       Zip,
       Max(country) as country,
       Phone,
       "Order Year",
       "Order Status"
  From (your_union_query)
Group by id, name, city, state,
       Zip, Phone, "Order Year", "Order Status"
```

Cheers!!